# What is the sed equivalent for "grep -o"?

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I would like the sed equivalent to:
`grep -Eo 'regex'`. 
I might, hypothetically, want to do further work with the output. 
This step might be just the first part of something
that will be more elaborate by adding `; s…` to a longer sed expression.

To be clearer, I want to be able to isolate each *string*
matching a given regular expression in an input stream. 
For proof-of-concept purposes,
each such string should be output as a separate line with no context
(i.e., no surrounding text from the input). 
So an input line with multiple (non-overlapping) matches
should result in multiple output lines;
an input line with no matches should result in no output.

#### Example:

**Regular expression:** `[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}`      
(i.e., three letters followed by four digits)

**Input:**

```
FGH1234 and CAS4057
MAX2345
```

**Output:**

```
FGH1234
CAS4057
MAX2345
```

Comment: Why not just use `grep` if it does what you want?

Comment: There is no `sed` equivalent for `grep` with the `-o` switch as the former is a completely different utility. The same result can be obtained with `awk` or `perl` or `python` but that wouldn't be true in every case because they don't function in the same way. As has been stated, it's best to just use what works rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I find this forum to be a great learning tool.  That said, I believe that constructive comments and answers are much more powerful than just comments asking why someone asks something, which I find here regularly and that sound like discouraging criticism.  Congratulations to those who answered the question.  That all said, I've been many times trying to find sed equivalents to grep, as sed allows me to do further work with the output.  Many times this step is just the first part of something that will be more elaborate by adding ";"s... to a longer sed expression.

Comment: @ilkkachu There are tons of cases where it would be useful to have an `-o` equivalent in `sed`, because you not only want to extract, but also modify at the same time. So often you find questions here that could be done so simple and elegant with that possibility, but will require a complicated mess of commands otherwise. For my personal use I implemented an `o` flag to the `s` command years ago. Maybe this question does encourage me to propose it to the maintainers.

Comment: @Philippos, perhaps, but the question didn't say anything about modifications. It only asked for a sed equivalent of that grep command, and grep doesn't do any modifications. (Well, other than removing the non-matching parts anyway.) That was the reason I asked why they wouldn't just use grep; if they actually wanted to do something slightly different, it would have been a perfectly fine answer to that. But if one is looking for help on something, I find it's useful to tell exactly _what_ they're looking for help on.

Comment: @Marcelo, the idea of being able to just add more sed commands to the end is a pretty one, but I don't think it's going to be that easy with the solutions presented here. The ones from rowboat and G-Man use labels to jump around, and end the sequence by deleting the just printed stuff. Say you wanted to wrap the matched outputs in brackets, so print `[FGH1234]` etc. instead. With G-Man's solution, you could add `s/^/[/; s/\n/]\n/;` just before the `P` at the end. But you can't add it to the end because it's printed before that, and you can't use `s/$/]/` because the matched part isn't at eol.

Comment: with rowboat's solution, that doesn't seem to work, and I'm guessing it's because those `s///` commands matching mess up the conditional jumps. So... if the goal is to do some other processing with the matched strings, and not just output them, it'd still be probably easier to just run the `grep -o` and pipe it to `sed`. Or switch to Perl or some other tool that allows juggling multiple strings at a time.

Comment: @ikkachu, the idea behind my comment is all about to incentive people and not discouraging them to ask.  Again, this forum is great learning tool.  My complementary comment about a use case is just something extra.  I'm a believer that, unless someone offends you, do something that hurts the community, cause any harm or violates the polices, if one don´t have anything constructive to say, the best is to say nothing.  Josho is a new user, and on his first question he already got a couple of "don't understand why you ask this" comments or answers...  Again, congrats to those who answered.

Comment: @Marcelo: They're asking for clarification. I don't know if you consider that discouraging, but if people stop asking for clarification, we're going to end up with a lot more unclear questions, a lot more wasted effort, and a less useful site overall.

Comment: @Marcelo, answering the "why" (or "what for") often helps in figuring out the "how".  In some cases, the answer that's _needed_ (not necessarily asked for) is "don't do that", or in nicer terms: "that approach is problematic because of this and that; it's better to do Z instead". Sure, one can ask just out of curiosity, but knowing it's about that is also helpful to get anyone answering it in the right frame of mind. (Important because people answering questions here may have a strong desire to help others do things the right way, instead of the more common obvious and flaky way.)

Comment: @Marcelo a common issue is we often have part of a solution in our head so we ask about implementing that solution instead of asking about how to solve the original problem. It's like someone asking "how can I hammer a nail using a screwdriver?". You can answer that, but the _real_ question here is probably "how can I hammer a nail" so asking "why a screwdriver?" lets us distinguish between "because all I have is a screwdriver" and "because I thought a screwdriver is the right tool". See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Team, agree, although I believe there are better ways of putting these comments then, like: What exactly are you trying to achieve that grep alone isn´t sufficient.  Anyway, thank you for the input, will consider this next time.  Also in the hope all can also consider improved ways to comment.  Since it sounded discouraging to me, there is a chance it also sounds discouraging to others.  Best wishes, #peace :-)

Comment: I went into a lumber store and asked to buy a ton of lumber.  They asked why.  I said, “I want to build a house.”  They looked at me and said, “You’re a computer programmer [geek/nerd], aren’t you?  There are companies that build houses.  Why don’t you just buy a house from a company that specializes in doing that?” … Seemed rude.   :-)   ⁠

Comment: @ilkkachu  `grep -o` is a GNU extension. A way to do `grep -o` using POSIX sed could be useful for someone somewhere.

Comment: @Kaz, okay, fair point about it being nonstandard. But it's not GNU-only: e.g. both Busybox and FreeBSD also support `-o`.

Comment: @ilkkachu even if that was relevant: POSIX does not require `grep -o`. As others have well said. Who cares if multiple implementations have it? Not all do. That's the point. Also it can help people learn if they want to. Learning how to do one thing in one [thing] can teach you OTHER things. I find it hard to believe that someone capable of writing your comments can't put that together. And I don't mean that as an insult. I mean it as you should think about those things too.

Comment: @NasirRiley you too. It's not standard. And if one learns how to do one thing with some tool they can at the same time learn other things. I find it hard to believe that you can't put that together. Who cares if it works in some implementations? That's utterly irrelevant.

Comment: @Pryftan I'm not sure what you're on about or if you even meant to reply to me because your response isn't relevant to my comment. What I stated about `sed` not having an equivalent to `grep -o` still stands simply because it's true. The person received responses that are based on objective facts that directly addressed the question which is the basis of this site. If someone wants to find other methods for doing something, then there is nothing stopping them from using Google and doing that on their own. Why does it even matter when this question hasn't received activing since last April?

Comment: @Pryftan, err, I know POSIX doesn't require `grep -o`, I just said "fair point about it being nonstandard" in that last comment (over a year ago). Since you ask: I care that multiple implementations have it, it's far more usable that way. (I would expect at least some BSD users also care they have it available.) In any case the claim I was that "`grep -o` is a GNU extension". It's not. I don't know who originated it, but at least it's not only a GNU extension any more. What exactly was your issue again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update to fix behaviour for zero-length regex matches:

```
sed 't match;s/REGEX/\n&\n/g;D;:match;/^\n/!P;s/\n//;D' file
```

Globally substitute matches with `<newline><matched part><newline>`. Then print them by creating a loop `P;s/\n//;D` back to `t match` and so on until all matched parts have been printed. `/^\n/!P` is used instead of just `P` so that only non-empty matches are printed (like GNU `grep -o` does).

A similar approach using `awk` could be:

```
regex='REGEX' awk 'BEGIN {FS="\n"}
  gsub(ENVIRON["regex"], FS "&" FS) {for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) if ($i!="") print $i}
' file
```

---

Original attempt: note that these commands behave badly when given a regex that matches an empty string (such as `.*`) - empty lines will be printed in an endless loop.

With a single invocation of `sed`:

```
sed '
t match
s/[[:alpha:]]\{3\}[[:digit:]]\{4\}/\
&\
/;D;:match
P;D' file
```

POSIX `sed` syntax is used: the regex is a basic regular expression, `\`-escaped newlines are used in the replacement string of `s///`, and newlines are used rather than `;` after the branch labels. Some versions of `sed` (such as GNU sed) can accept the script all on one line:

```
sed 't match;s/[[:alpha:]]\{3\}[[:digit:]]\{4\}/\n&\n/;D;:match;P;D' file
```

The substitution isolates the first match by adding newlines before and after the matching portion. The conditional branch `t match` at the start of the script will only be followed after a successful substitution is made. `:match` is where the matching portion is printed. `D` is used so that the line containing the match is removed from the pattern space and the remainder used as input for the next cycle, allowing further matches to be found.

Comment: Excellent! Very elegant.

Comment: This script goes into an endless loop for regexps that match strings of zero length (like `x*`).

Comment: Try `echo Hello | sed 't match;s/e*/\n&\n/g;D;:match;P;s/\n//;D'` one empty line per each empty match between characters.

Comment: @QuartzCristal Try it with `/^\n/!P` for printing

Answer (score 7):

This is very similar to [rowboat’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/712810/80216) (but developed independently),
and with maybe slightly more verbose explanation.

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -En 't dummy; : dummy; s/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}/&\n/; T; s/.*([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}\n)/\1/; P; D'
```

Explanation:

- `-E`  
  Use extended regular expressions (EREs). 
  Without this, we would have to say `\{3\}` and `\{4\}`.
- `n`  
  Don’t print anything automatically; print only what we say to print. 
  This is desirable because, like `grep`, we want to print nothing
  for input lines that don’t contain strings matching the regular expression.
- `t dummy; : dummy` 
  Jump to the immediately following (“`dummy`”) label. 
  This is a conditional jump, so it might or might not happen. 
  But it doesn’t matter,
  because there’s nothing between the jump command and the label.

  This looks like a no-op, and it sort-of is, except it clears sed’s memory
  of whether there has been a successful **s**ubstitute command.
- `s/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}/&\n/` 
  Look for the OP’s regex. 
  If found, replace it by itself plus a newline (i.e., add a newline).
- `T`  
  If the above substitute command failed (didn’t find the pattern),
  jump to the end of the script and read the next line of input. 
  [Documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) for `T` says,

  > `T label`
  >
  >   If no
  >   `s///`
  >   has done a successful substitution
  >   since the last input line was read and since the last
  >   `t`
  >   or
  >   `T`
  >   command,
  >   then branch to
  >   *`label`*
  >   ; if
  >   *`label`*
  >   is omitted, branch to end of script. 
  >   This is a GNU extension.

  So that’s why we did the thing with the `dummy` label —
  so that *this* `T` command would look at
  only the immediately previous `s` command.
- `s/.*([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}\n)/\1/` 
  Look for the OP’s regex, preceded by any number of any characters (**`.*`**)
  and followed by a newline,
  and replace them with just the regex match and the newline
  (i.e., delete any text before the regex match). 
  At first glance, this looks like it might find the *last* match on the line,
  because **`.*`** is greedy. 
  But it finds the first, because only the first match
  is followed by a newline (because the first `s` wasn’t **g**lobal).
- `P` 
  ***(capital* P*)*** 
  Print the pattern buffer through the first newline. 
  This is simply the string that matched the regex
  (just like what `grep -o` would output).
- `D`  
  Delete the pattern buffer through the first newline
  and jump to the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to get the same output as grep with GNU sed calling it twice in a pipe:

```
sed -E 's/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}/\n&\n/g' input \ 
 | sed -E '/^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$/!d'
```

In concept:

```
sed    -E 's/REGEX/\n&\n/g' input \ 
 | sed -E '/^REGEX$/!d'
```

The first call isolates the matched regex with newlines around it.

The second call `deletes` all lines that doesn't match the regex.

Which, in effect, prints only lines matching the regex exactly as `grep -o` does it.

Trying to use some extended regex to match, and also remove leading, or trailing, no needed, parts is meant to fail. The regex engines will match too much (as any `*`) is not limited and will match `as much as possible`. Building a PCRE with lookaround matches might solve this problem, but sed (any present day sed) is not able to use PCREs.

This solution is simple and with no known problems (other than that it will print many empty lines if the regex could match "nothing").

Trying to reduce this use to a single line sed gets (surprisingly) quite complex. The other answers have tried to get that done with several corner cases and complex sed syntax.

We will keep trying to find a general solution.

Answer (score 3):

Only with GNU sed , three ways can be:

```
sed -En '
  s/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}/\n&\n/g
  s/.*\n(.*\n)/\1/Mg
  s/(.*)\n.*/\1/p
' file

# or without -n
sed -E '
  s/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}/\n&\n/
  s/.*\n//M;/\n/P;D
' file

# Or using the -n option
sed -En '
  s/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}/\n&\n/
  s/.*\n//M;T;P;D
' file
```

---

Output:

```
FGH1234
CAS4057
MAX2345
```

Comment: If you have GNU sed, you probably have GNU grep with `-o`.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4})[a-z ]+/\1\n/;ta' input_file
FGH1234
CAS4057
MAX2345
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}) [^A-Z]*/\1\
/' input_file
FGH1234
CAS4057
MAX2345
```

Comment: Have you tried some text before the first match, like: `$'dgdg FGH1234 and CAS4057\nMAX2345 fhjd hdd' ?

Comment: I haven’t bothered to look at your POSIX solution.  Your GNU solution produces the desired output from the given input.  You know what else produces the desired output?  `printf '%s\n' FGH1234 CAS4057 MAX2345`.  The question says “… equivalent to: `grep -Eo …`.  Your GNU sed solution fails (1) If the first line doesn’t begin with a pattern. (2) If any line doesn’t end with a pattern. (3) If two patterns are separated by any character other than a lower-case letter or a space (for example, `aaa1111 and/or bbb2222`, `ccc3333  &  ddd4444`, `eee5555 AND fff6666` or `ggg7777, hhh8888`).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Or if two patterns are consecutive (e.g., `abc1234xyz9999`).  (5) Or if two patterns are separated by a space and the second one begins with a lower-case letter (e.g., `bid1234 eBa5678`). … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … I do not guarantee that this list of bugs is complete or exhaustive.